favicon disappears when running the pipeline, but it works on localhost, how can I solve this?
I'm encountering an issue with the favicon in my Angular application. The favicon works perfectly fine when I run the application locally, but after deploying it to the server, the favicon disappears. I've confirmed that the favicon.ico file is included in the dist folder after the build process. However, once deployed, it doesn't show up, and it also fails when I trigger a pipeline build.
Angular Version: 15
What I've Tried:
Adjusted the Favicon Path:
I initially had the href in the index.html set to "favicon.ico", which worked fine locally but not in production.
I then tried setting it to an absolute path "/favicon.ico", assuming it might be a relative path issue, but this didn't fix the problem either.
Cleared Cache and Tested in Incognito Mode:
To rule out any issues related to browser caching, I cleared the browser cache and tested the deployment in incognito mode, but the favicon still did not appear.
Verified the Favicon in the dist Folder:
After building the application, I checked the contents of the dist folder and confirmed that the favicon.ico is indeed present there.
I also checked the structure and confirmed that the index.html is correctly referencing the favicon file.
Disabled Output Hashing Temporarily:
Suspecting that outputHashing: "all" might be causing the issue, I temporarily disabled output hashing to see if it affected the favicon, but there was no change in the outcome.
Checked Server Configuration:
I reviewed the server configuration to ensure that it was serving static files correctly, including the favicon.ico. However, everything seemed to be in order on the server side.
Tested Access to Favicon Directly:
I tried to access the favicon.ico directly via the browser using the after deployment, but the file could not be found or did not load as expected.
